# AmCharts - Multiple Data Sets - without percentages as compare values

Tags: amcharts

Simple question - I have amcharts simmilar to this:

http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/

I want it that way, that the value axis to the left won't be shown as percentages, but as actual values. The second thing is that I want the charts to be with their exact values - not converted by the percentages. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it is possible - set recalculateToPercents:"never" for the StockPanel and the values won't be recalculated.

Comment: Wow, so easy! Thanks! Is it possible then to show all the values while comparing? I have a lot of data which aren't in the same time moments, so they aren't shown when I use compare. I have to use grouping, but I wanted to avoid that. Is that possible to show all the values then?

Comment: to turn off grouping, set CategoryAxesSettings.maxSeries = 0;

Comment: I know that, it is really what I am using now. But if the data isn't grouped like that it won't show data from compared dataSets if they aren't intersecting with each other

Comment: Unfortunately there is now way to do that then.

Comment: Okay well I will just use maxSeries = 1000 and proper grouping parts. It will group but I won't lose too much data in the process.